# Firebase Hosting Deleted Deployments Taking Up Space

Tags: firebase, deployment, storage, hosting, firebase-hosting

I am using Firebase to host a small site (~6 mb), yet I noticed the usage meter is showing a much higher number. I realized that old deployments counted towards storage, so I deleted them. However, the usage meter shows the same amount of storage.

Is there a time period before the old deployments are truly deleted? I can't imagine you are forced to keep consuming storage space.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out it took roughly 24 hours for the changes to take effect.

Others mileage may vary, as this is anecdotal.